# Site Columns Usage from Power Platform

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, power-automate, powerapp, site-column

I have the following requirement, please help me find an optimal solution for the same:

**Site Column / Content Type usage from Power Platform:**
I need to find out the list of Power Automates, Power Apps, and Power BI reports that use custom site columns from a few specific content types.
Is there any automated way, tool, or script available to generate this type of report?

Comment: not as far as I know. You will need to look into each flow, form or dataset to see if the column is used.

Comment: agreed with teylyn, there is no such tool to achieve it. you need to check manually.